# Mobile application usage tracking library

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, mobile, symbian, analytics

Earlier we were using [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) (which is primarily a crash reporting library for Android apps) for tracking our Android application usage but [Google Analytics for mobile](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/overview.html) also seems to be nice, the only issue is that Google Analytics library is only for Android and iOS but for our target market we are building Symbian and WP7 version as well.

So, I am looking for options which will help me with:

- Tracking Application usage
- Recording Custom Variables

Is there something like ACRA/GA which works for Android, Symbian and WP7.

Comment: This blog post discusses a few options for WP7, including GA (twice): http://mark.mymonster.nl/2011/10/21/statistics-for-your-windows-phone-application-google-analytics

Comment: And if google reject our country to use google analytics, what can i do? Is there any other library?

Answer (score 0):

Check out mtiks. http://www.mtiks.com/

"A comprehensive analytics platform for iOS (iPhone/iPad), Windows Phone 7, Android, Blackberry and Mono app developers. Offers a real-time app analytics and additional services to support app developers. mtiks helps app developers to manage app events or attributes, errors or many others. Simple, easy to integrate."

Comment: Please consider writing a short description of the library you're posting a link to...